# JSON String not getting correct value returning error

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, twilio, twilio-php

I am new to server and twilio, i have set up the server to generate access token correctly on my localhost. When i generate a token using

```
http://localhost/index.php?identity=bob&room=example
```

The token generated is in jwt, I get the correct token because if i put it in application directly, i get connected but when i try to call it using the function :

```
(void)retrieveAccessTokenFromURL:(NSString *)tokenURLStr
                    completion:(void (^)(NSString* token, NSError *err)) completionHandler {
NSURL *tokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString:tokenURLStr];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithURL:tokenURL
                                    completionHandler: ^(NSData * _Nullable data,
                                                         NSURLResponse * _Nullable response,
                                                         NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                        NSError *err = error;
                                        NSString *accessToken;
                                        NSString *identity;
                                        if (!err) {
                                            if (data != nil) {
                                                NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                                                     options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                                                                       error:&err];
                                                if (!err) {
                                                    accessToken = json[@"token"];
                                                    identity = json[@"identity"];
                                                    NSLog(@"Logged in as %@",identity);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        completionHandler(accessToken, err);
                                    }];
[task resume];
```

}

It generates an error `err ->   NSError *   domain: @"NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 3840  0x1559ef60` , i checked it said to `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments` but still it is giving me the same error whereas the same token is working great when put directly. If any one can help me out it will be great. Thanks in advance.

## **Edit 1**

Here is the generated token :

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImN0eSI6InR3aWxpby1mcGE7dj0xIn0.eyJqdGkiOiJTS2I2M2RjMzE2Yjc0ZDdhN2E0YzEyNjYzNDJlNTY2MTcwLTE0OTc5OTIzMTMiLCJpc3MiOiJTS2I2M2RjMzE2Yjc0ZDdhN2E0YzEyNjYzNDJlNTY2MTcwIiwic3ViIjoiQUM5ZTliNDYxZDI4NDkzZWY2ODYwNDMzYzViZWRkOTk0YyIsImV4cCI6MTQ5Nzk5NTkxMywiZ3JhbnRzIjp7ImlkZW50aXR5IjoiYm9iIiwidmlkZW8iOnsicm9vbSI6ImV4YW1wbGUifX19.Ppe85LeD8CFatGXkXgzaTR_ljznXIrpyrb8lu3SR4xo
```

I checked it on jwt.io

```
 HEADER:ALGORITHM & TOKEN TYPE

{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "HS256",
  "cty": "twilio-fpa;v=1"
}
PAYLOAD:DATA

{
  "jti": "SKb63dc316b74d7a7a4c1266342e566170-1497992313",
  "iss": "SKb63dc316b74d7a7a4c1266342e566170",
  "sub": "AC9e9b461d28493ef6860433c5bedd994c",
  "exp": 1497995913,
  "grants": {
    "identity": "bob",
    "video": {
      "room": "example"
    }
  }
}
VERIFY SIGNATURE
HMACSHA256(
  base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
  base64UrlEncode(payload),
  
secret

)
```

Also when i give this token directly the connection works, but through the url it is not working.

Website code :

```
    <?php
include('./vendor/autoload.php');
include('./config.php');

use Twilio\Jwt\AccessToken;
use Twilio\Jwt\Grants\VideoGrant;

// Use identity and room from query string if provided
$identity = isset($_GET["identity"]) ? $_GET["identity"] : "identity";
$room = isset($_GET["room"]) ? $_GET["room"] :  "";

    
// Create access token, which we will serialize and send to the client
$token = new AccessToken(
    $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, 
    $TWILIO_API_KEY, 
    $TWILIO_API_SECRET, 
    3600, 
    $identity
);

// Grant access to Video
$grant = new VideoGrant();
$grant->setRoom($room);
$token->addGrant($grant);

echo $token->toJWT();
```

Comment: Can you share what your JSON object produced by the PHP server looks like?

Comment: Edit updated in question. Thank you

Comment: Are you returning the data as a string or as a JSON object though?

Comment: I am using the same code as in the quickstart tutorial on twilio website for php.. I will update the code for that too

Comment: updated the code with the one on php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In the server side code you are returning a simple string, not JSON.

You have two options now. You can either turn the returned `data` into an `NSString` and that will be your token. This won't include your identity though, which you are currently logging. To get the identity too, you can alter the return value from the server to actually return JSON with the token and the identity. Then your JSON parsing code should work.

For option 1, you need to turn the `NSData` into an `NSString`. You should be able to do that like this:

```
NSString *accessToken = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

For the alternative, where you keep your JSON parsing code and return JSON from the server, change the last few lines of your PHP to:

```
$grant = new VideoGrant();
$grant->setRoom($room);
$token->addGrant($grant);

$data = array('identity'=>$identity, 'token'=>$token->toJWT());
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: it is just printing "Array" in the second part and nothing inside it.. sorry not much familiar with php

Comment: Argh! I forgot one thing... sorry. That's my fault. Check the answer in a minute when I've edited.

Comment: No worries :) If this has sorted it for you, do you mind marking it as correct, so that anyone else with this issue can see it did work. Cheers!

Comment: ah sorry mate.. think so got it marked twice.. :)
already done .. thanks again :)